# Need firmware for CreatorBot 3d Pro II?

Tags: firmware, software

I lost the operating system in my CreatorBot 3D Pro II. How do I go about recovering the firmware?

[Further details about how I lost the "operating system" are forthcoming]

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing Stack Exchange.  Please take the [tour] and read the [FAQ] to get a better understanding of how this site works.  Also, have you checked the manufacturer's site for a firmware download?  What else have you done in terms of finding out what you actually need?

Comment: You mean this printer: https://3dprinterworks-dev.myshopify.com/products/creatorbot-3d-pro-series-ii-max

Comment: Don't you just need to reflash the board with new firmware? That should be detailed in the manual.